# Why is my code expecting a primary expression in a switch case before curly brackets?

Tags: c++, enums, compiler-errors, switch-statement

I am trying to use a switch case as a sort of menu selection for the user in my code. I have this enum list:

`enum menuChoice {ADD = 1, REMOVE = 2, DISPLAY = 3, SEARCH = 4, RESULTS = 5, QUIT = 6};`

Then I have this code:

```
        menuChoice switchChoice;
        Student student;

        cout << "1. Add\n" << "2. Remove\n" << "3. Display\n" << "4. Search\n";
        cout << "5. Results\n" << "6. Quit" << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < 999; ++i)
        {
                cout << "Please enter choice:";

                cin >> userChoice;

                if (userChoice > 6 || userChoice < 1)
                {
                        cout << "Incorrect choice. Please enter again" << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                        break;
                }
        }

        switchChoice = static_cast<menuChoice>(userChoice);
        switch(switchChoice){

        case 1:
                add_Student(student);

                break;
        case 2:

                break;
        case 3:

                break;
        case 4:

                break;
        case 5:

                break;
        case 6:
                break;

        default:
        }
```

Which is kicking back this error:

```
 error: expected primary-expression before ‘}’ token
```

I am really scratching my head over this. What is the mistake here? How am I not implementing a primary expression? I know that you aren't supposed to pass types to switch parameters but this is an enum variable I'm passing. Some help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`default: }` is a syntax error. The `default` label  must be followed by a statement or a block. (This applies to any othe sort of label too).

For example it could be `default: break;` or `default: ;` or `default: {}` .

Comment: That was the solution. However embarrassing, I'm glad I got it sorted. I appreciate the information.